# How to switch off Outlook Synchronization Manager

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have one strange thing which is happening to my outlook. It tries to synchronize something (seems it do this every time send/receive triggers). Does anybody know how to switch this manager off?

Here is the icon of the sync manager in the task bar (left one) https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9085558_69411843_95701

Thanks in advance!

p.s. it's also annoying me that something gone wrong and sync failed. Also every time it tries to sync something internet explorer says me that there are too many temporary internet files and asking me to expand space for its storing. https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D9085558_69411843_95781

Please, help! This makes me crazy.

Comment: Please upload pictures of the issue instead of sending us to another site where we have to download them. You can do this in the [edit screen](http://superuser.com/posts/477404/edit)

Comment: @DaveRook, I would be glad to add, but as I don't have 10 reputation pts, I'm unable to do this. If you need, I can upload it somewhere else.

Comment: Does it not even let you add them as a link? If so, a mod can update it for you